# Where is the arrange components inside area button in Altium 19?

Tags: pcb, altium

Why in the world do people reduce functionality of software when they create a new revision? And why can't people out that two clicks takes more time than one, they've hidden all the buttons in Altium 19

Anyway, I'm looking for this button. I need it for my PCB layout workflow. Usually I'd highlight components in the schematic, then group them. I absolutley hate the rooms feature of altium. There hast to be a better way to duplicate circuits. Anyway...

Where is the arrange components inside area button in Altium 19?

Or how can I group selected components?

Looks like this in older versions:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `Arrange Components Inside Area` is buried within the `Alignment Tools` menu on the toolbar. I was not able to find a way to customize the toolbar to move the icon out of the submenu and onto the toolbar.

[image: Arrange Components Inside Area]

As @asdfex does, I use the keyboard shortcuts more than buttons. Primarily because of this very reason: they change style and position more often than warranted.

Comment: Thanks I don't have those toolbars by default, I suppose they need to be enabled?

Comment: @VoltageSpike It seems so. From the 'normal' toolbar, I could not find any way to get to the same function. This seems to be an annoying setback for those who rely on the buttons being easily accessible.

Answer (score 1):

There was an icon for that? I never used it - I try to memorize the 2- or 3-letter shortcuts, which is even faster than clicking an icon because you don't have to move the mouse away from the PCB and the second hand is already on the keyboard.

For arranging components within a rectangle that shortcut is T-O-L. (Easy to remember, because it is a "great" feature, and "great" is "toll" in German :-P )
This shortcut didn't change in the past years.